# iReport: How to give my choice of custom labels to Pie chart for a computed count?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am new to *JasperReports* and I am trying to generate a Pie Chart using *iReports 5.1.0*.

I have counts of days taken which should compute the percentages of the 3 slices but what should I give in the Key Expression and Label Expression ?
Trying to customize the 3 slice labels as Within 5 days, More than 5 days and Tested but not referred.

I am getting counts through this code

```sql
SELECT SUM(subSet.days_taken <= 5) AS within_5_days,
       SUM(subSet.days_taken > 5) AS more_than_5,
       SUM(subSet.date_referred IS NULL) as not_yet_referred
FROM (select p.patient_id,
               (CASE
                 WHEN st.smear_result <> 'NEGATIVE' OR st.gxp_result = 'MTB+' THEN (DATEDIFF(r.date_referred, MIN(st.date_smear_tested)))
                 ELSE
                  (CASE
                 WHEN st.smear_result = 'NEGATIVE' OR st.gxp_result = 'MTB-' THEN  (DATEDIFF(r.date_referred, MAX(st.date_smear_tested)))

                END) END) as days_taken,
                r.date_referred as date_referred
          from patient as p
          left outer join sputum_test as st on p.patient_id = st.patient_id
          left outer join referral as r on r.patient_id = st.patient_id
         where p.suspected_by is not null
           and (p.patient_status = 'SUSPECT' or
               p.patient_status = 'CONFIRMED')
         group by p.patient_id) 
         as subSet
```

This is also the DataSet run I am using.

Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you do now is that you make three columns in one tuple so you probably get something similar to the following:'

```
--------------------------------------------------
| within_5_days | more_than_5 | not_yet_referred |
--------------------------------------------------
|       4       |       5     |       8          |
--------------------------------------------------
```

However the pie chart won't accept it in that format. Instead you want this:

```
-------------------------
|     Type       | Summ | 
-------------------------
|within_5_days   |  4   |
|more_than_5     |  5   |
|not_yet_referred|  8   |
-------------------------
```

With that you can have "Type" as your label expression and "Sum" as value expression. So you would have to change the query to something like this

```
select CASE 
   WHEN subSet.days_taken <= 5 THEN 'within_5_days' 
   WHEN subSet.days_taken > 5 THEN 'more_than_5' 
   WHEN subSet.date_referred IS NULL THEN 'not_yet_referred'
END CASE AS Type, 1 AS Summ ...
```

Then you can sum it.